Does the density $f_X$ of a random variable $X$ always have $\int_a^b f_X = P(a < X \leq b)$?
Is the below equation always true for the probability density function $f_X(x)$ of a random variable $X$?
$$
\int_a^b f_X(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = P(a < X \leq b) \quad \text{if } a < b
$$
The official solution (refer to Q.8 - c in link) just says it's not always true, but has no explanation. But I don't understand why it shouldn't be because isn't this exactly how probability density function defined?

It is is true for any random variable $X$ having a density function $f_X$.

@geetha290krm I agree but the solution says it's not always true. I am referring to Q.8 - c) in the link

Look at this question and its answer. Not a complete answer to my understanding, but it addresses your question

@RafaBudría from what I understand is that $X$ might follow the Cantor distribution which Wikipedia says has no density function. But I feel like the question isn't asking about whether the density function exists or not but rather if the statement holds or not.

The equation in the OP is always correct as $f_X$ is a pdf. Any random variable $X$ with a pdf is a continuous random variable for which $\mathbb P(X=a)=0$ for all $a\in \mathbb R$ (in fact, for any continuous random variable with or without a pdf this property holds).

The answer, that I think the authors of the document have in mind, can be found in the corresponding lecture notes on https://engineering.purdue.edu/~reibman/ece302/. At the end of "topic 2.2" (https://engineering.purdue.edu/~reibman/ece302/LectureNotes/Topic2.2b-PDF.pdf), the authors describe what I think they have in mind regarding this question: $\mathbb{P}(X = a) = 0$ should hold. This is fulfilled if the random variable is continuous or the cdf is continous at $x=a$ (as is said in the lecture notes). I think a good example, where this won't hold would be a mixture distribution of a point mass at $a$ and a continuous distribution.

Thank you! I just assumed that $X$ was continuous and therefore came to the conclusion $P(a < X \leq b) = P(a \leq X \leq b)$.

I think the answer is wrong. For $X$ to have a probability density function, it must be absolutely continuous, at least according to Wikipedia's definition: "absolutely continuous probability distributions are exactly those with a probability density function."
And if $X$ is absolutely continuous, then your equation is always true.
